# How to debug a Python script that takes input from a Powershell script in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, powershell, debugging, visual-studio-code

Basic Info:

- OS = Windows 10 Version 1909
- Powershell 5.1
- Python 3.9.1
- Visual Studio Code Version 1.56.2

I work for a water district, and we monitor the water quality for 7 reservoirs. Each reservoir has its own folder of data. We also have a master Excel file where each reservoir has its own sheet. The master file runs to about 2015 for each reservoir. My job is to update the master file so it contains data to 2020.

To do this I have written two scripts. The first is a Powershell script. Its job is to go into the master file for Lake A's sheet, find the last sampling date that was uploaded, and then use that date to find the excel files that need to be uploaded in Lake A's folder. Those files are then piped into a python script for formatting the files, concatenating them together, and then concatenating that output to Lake A's master file.

So I've been working on Lake A and everything is looking good. I tried running my scripts on Lake B, and my python script is raising some errors. I can't debug the python script by itself because it needs input from the powershell script. Is there a way to configure the debugger so that two scripts work together?

I'm new to Visual Studio Code, so I'm confused on how to use all the different json files.

I know for configuring the debugger for Python, there is a configuration option called "args"(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options). I'm not sure if this would be flexible enough for what I want. I could do something like `{args:["LakeB"]}` in the launch.json file, but what happens when I need to debug Lake C?

I read in Visual Studio Code's general information about debugging that you can set a "preLaunchTask" (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging). Could that possibly work? But then would I need to create a task that creates the arguments needed for debugging the python script?

Basically, it would be nice if I could find a way to setup the debugger so it prompts me to input which reservoir I want to work on.

Thanks

Comment: SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Why is this tagged `PowerShell` at all? As this is a  'How do I debug in VSCode' or a `Teach me to cross-language debug in VSCode`, question? Thus off-topic.

Comment: @thalhuber - It should at least be possible to write the PowerShell script output to a file and specify this file as input when starting the Python script in the debugger.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. 
We are here to help, but our time is valuable and so I recommand you 
to take the time for a [mre]. 
The chances to get an answer are much higher than without. 
If you haven't done yet, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 and read [ask]. In addition I suggest to 
[format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question well, 
and you do can check out all of the points in this 
[checklist](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)